# Parsing json with MongoDB and Amazon API Gateway

Tags: json, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I would like to get data from a mongodb database when I access an Amazon API Gateway invoke URL. 
My lambda handler is written in Python and looks something like this:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return collection.find({})
```

The problem is, that the pymongo-cursor is not serializable to json format because of the mongodb ObjectIds and datetime objects. I have tried to use the `bson.json_util` tool, but then i get a response like this:

```
{
"data": [
    "{\"content\": \"something\", \"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"some id\"}}", 
    "{\"content\": \"something\", \"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"some id \"}}", 
    "{\"content\": \"something\", \"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"some id\"}}"
   ]
}
```

I suspect I get the above result, because the api gateway formats the return data as Json, resulting in the return data getting encoded twice.

Is there a way to stop amazon api gateway from encoding the data to json, so I can use the `bson.json_util`? Or is there another way to make the pymongo-cursor serializable to json format without formatting twice?

Comment: If AWS api gateway is already sending a json object then why you are again  converting it to json object ?

Comment: Tried mapping templates in API gateway?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference

Comment: @Aky_0788 AWS api gateway automatically converts it to a json object, but it fails as the data contains ObjectId's and datetime-objects.

Comment: @nightgaunt What do you mean? I am unsure how to use the mapping templates for what i trying to do.